# execute[wait for tomcat7] action run,

Tags: tomcat, jenkins, amazon-ec2, chef-infra, knife

I am setting up a continuous delivery pipeline which,

1. creates a new aws instance,
2. Installs all the necessary software to run the web app,
3. Deploys the web app to tomcat and
4. Runs some Rake tests deployed from a GitHub test repo.

All is good so far. I have set up Jenkins to execute a shell script with the following command,

```
 sudo knife ec2 server create -r 'recipe[apt],recipe[java],recipe[mysql_install],recipe[tomcat],recipe[deploy_tests_from_github],recipe[configure_db],recipe[deploy-app],recipe[start_tests]' -V
```

The deployments go fine. The only problem is that when the tests start, Chef seems to have shutdown tomcat, thus Watir cannot browse to the web app.

Most of the recipes are cloned straight from Chef Supermarket and I am using this cookbook for tomcat https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/tomcat

and my start_test recipe is simple

```
execute "start_test" do
    command '/usr/local/bin/rake'
    cwd '/Watir_tests/test'
end
```

Here is part of my output,

```
ec2-52-88-49-226.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com [0mRecipe: Deploy_App

::default[0m
ec2-52-88-49-226.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com   * service[tomcat7] action stop
ec2-52-88-49-226.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com     [32m- stop service service[tomcat7][0m
ec2-52-88-49-226.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com [0m  * execute[wait for tomcat7] action run
ec2-52-88-49-226.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com     [32m- execute sleep 5[0m
ec2-52-88-49-226.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com [0m  * remote_file[MyApp.war] action create
ec2-52-88-49-226.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com     [32m- create new file /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/MyApp.war[0m
ec2-52-88-49-226.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com     [32m- update content in file /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/MyApp.war from none to cd2ac4[0m
ec2-52-88-49-226.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com     [37m(file sizes exceed 10000000 bytes, diff output suppressed)[0m
ec2-52-88-49-226.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com [0m  * service[tomcat7] action start
ec2-52-88-49-226.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com     [32m- start service service[tomcat7][0m
ec2-52-88-49-226.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com [0m  * execute[wait for tomcat7] action run
ec2-52-88-49-226.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com     [32m- execute sleep 5[0m
ec2-52-88-49-226.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com [0mRecipe: start_tests::default[0m
ec2-52-88-49-226.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com   * execute[start_test] action run
ec2-52-88-49-226.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com     [0m
ec2-52-88-49-226.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com     ================================================================================[0m
ec2-52-88-49-226.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com     [31mError executing action `run` on resource 'execute[start_test]'[0m
ec2-52-88-49-226.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com     ================================================================================[0m
ec2-52-88-49-226.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com     
ec2-52-88-49-226.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com [0m    Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed[0m
ec2-52-88-49-226.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com     ------------------------------------[0m
ec2-52-88-49-226.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com     Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
ec2-52-88-49-226.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com [0m    ---- Begin output of /usr/local/bin/rake ----
ec2-52-88-49-226.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com [0m    STDOUT: Run options: --seed 62510
ec2-52-88-49-226.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com [0m    
ec2-52-88-49-226.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com [0m    # Running:
ec2-52-88-49-226.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com [0m    
ec2-52-88-49-226.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com [0m    EEEEEE
ec2-52-88-49-226.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com [0m    
ec2-52-88-49-226.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com [0m    Finished in 330.793031s, 0.0181 runs/s, 0.0000 assertions/s.
ec2-52-88-49-226.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com [0m    
    Error:
ec2-52-88-49-226.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com [0m    LogInWithWrongPasswordTest#test_log_in_with_wrong_credentials:
ec2-52-88-49-226.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com [0m    **Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException: unable to locate element, using {:id=>"logInform:userName", :tag_name=>"input or textarea", :type=>"(any text type)"}**
ec2-52-88-49-226.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com [0m        /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.8.0/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/element.rb:533:in `assert_element_found'
ec2-52-88-49-226.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com [0m        /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.8.0/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/element.rb:505:in `assert_exists'
ec2-52-88-49-226.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com [0m        /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.8.0/lib/watir-webdriver/user_editable.rb:32:in `clear'
ec2-52-88-49-226.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com [0m        /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.8.0/lib/watir-webdriver/user_editable.rb:11:in `set'
ec2-52-88-49-226.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com [0m        /Watir_tests/Pages/LogInPage.rb:14:in `login'
ec2-52-88-49-226.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com [0m        /Watrit_tests/test/log_in_with_wrong_password_test.rb:15:in `test_log_in_with_wrong_credentials'
ec2-52-88-49-226.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com [0m    
ec2-52-88-49-226.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com [0m
```

As you can see, Watir cannot find the webpage elements because tomcat is not running at that moment.

Has anyone else come across something like this? Is there a solution?

Please also advise if calling a Knife ec2 server create command from Jenkins is advisable.

Thank you.

Comment: Is it not that your tomcat is started but the webapp has not finished starting/deploying ? (`sleep 5` is not really long, and the service start is asynchronous IIRC, I would better loop grepping 'Server startup' in a tail of catalina.out and sleep 1m , maybe failing if after 5 mins the server is not started)

Answer (score 0):

Long version of my comment above I would do (untested code, there can be typo):

```
bash "Wait tomcat started" do
  code << -EOH
    for i in {1..10}; do
       tail -n 100 /path/to/catalina.out | grep "Server Startup" && exit 0
       sleep 20 
    done
    exit 1
  EOH
 notifies :run,"execute[start_test]", :immediately
end
```

The idea is to check the server has finished starting (greping the Startup line in the 100 last line of log, in case your app is chatty in logs) and notify the tests to start if yes, or fail after 200 secs (10 times with a 20 sec interval)

I assume (still untested) something like this could do too and is cleaner:

```
execute "tail -n 100 /path/to/catalina.out | grep "Server Startup" do
  retries 10 
  retry_delay 20 
  notifies :run,'execute[start_test]', :immediately
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can add test page and wait when tomcat has started

```
until (curl http://localhost:8080/status/ | grep "READY")
    do sleep 10
done
```